# how to remove the height of div when item removed from it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm showing a list of items in a div. When any of the item is clicked, it will append to the div above. I didn't set any height for this div.Item here will appear with a delete icon beside each item. Once deleted, that particular item will append to the div below which it originated from. Problem now, as items added to the above div, it's height grows and once items deleted, I expect the height would reduce too, but it remains the same. Thus when I add one more item into the above div,it grows even longer. How do I remove the height of the first div?

Pictured below describe the flow:last picture shows what happens after all items deleted from first red box and new item added into it.

[image]
[image][image]

Here's my code for what happens when the delete button clicked.

```
 function hide_rate(param)
 {

     //remove item
     $("#wrapper_"+param).text(" ");
     $("input[name=rate_"+param+"]").val(" ");
     $("input[name=rate_"+param+"]").empty();
     $(".cross_"+param).text(" "); 
     $("#moveItem").css("background-color","#ff0000");
     //add back removed item

     $("#displaySubItems").append($(".sub_"+param+" span").text()+"<br/>");

 }
```

Comment: why don't you try `height:auto`

Comment: Add your code to the question.

Comment: @Amitsingh, I tried that too..doesn't work

Comment: please share your code or a fiddle will be great

Comment: Please add your code to your question otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: @Vamsi, added my code

Comment: your code is still not clear, but according to me the <br /> tag is creating issue, as you are only clearing the text and not removing Br /> tag

Comment: You need to go to the way of remove-insert DOM nodes instead of set-clear node text. And why do you use `div` to show the list? There is `<ul>` tag for showing lists

Comment: @vani, you are supposed to delete the node/wrapper instead of making the text/value/ empty. Also, you have to remove the breakline element which was appended after each node.

Answer (score 3):

Using function `empty()` :retains the element in DOM for eg:

```
<div class="hello">Hello</div>
<div class="goodbye">Goodbye</div>

$("div.hello").empty();
```

will only delete the text Hello from the div thereby retaining the div and         thus the SPACE

```
ie. it wil result in
<div class="hello"></div>
<div class="goodbye">Goodbye</div>
```

However,using remove() will remove the element from the DOM and hence the space retained due to the use of empty() wil be eliminated.

So, use
`$("div.hello").remove();`  to get desired output ie.

```
<div class="goodbye">Goodbye</div>
```